# Docker based Elastic Search container stopped due to with a log " java.io.IOException: No space left on device" is /dev/sda have 24G free space

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I am using a dockerized magento setup from this [github link](https://gitlab.dev9server.com/swetank_nhz/magento-2.3.6-dockerize.git)

I am using main "docker-compose.yml" file from the repo

```
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: build/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - node.name=node-1
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-1
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearchdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticconfig/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - <project_name>-network
```

In this  already add the volume to make elastic-data persist
after that everything is running pretty well but after a month i am facing an error from elastic search container logs that

```
"java.io.IOException: No space left on device"
```

and when i checked /dev/sda have 24G free space

So i am not sure my i am facing this now and container is failed to restart or run.
just provide a little path toward the solution that would be enough!!! and thank Already

Comment: Can you paste the output of df -h and df -h from within the docker container

Comment: `
[root@7ebd9c0f0777 elasticsearch]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         315G  282G   18G  95% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda        315G  282G   18G  95% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/firmware
`

Comment: Looks fine to me. Still, if you're okay deleting existing data then you can try deleting docker volume. `docker volume rm {}`

Comment: @DhireshJain That may work but still i dont;want any data loss moreover if we can increase this 7.9G /sys/fs/cgroup  partition size that i may not get face similar. do you have any ref about it